# Is the Quantum Gravity mystery already solved by Susskind?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, quantum-gravity, ads-cft, holographic-principle

Very recently, Leonard Susskind presented a lecture presenting his proposal of Quantum Mechanics = Gravity (equality means duality).

[Quantum Origins of Gravity](https://youtu.be/-OkwGDKoY0o)

Is this really the end of Quantum Gravity problem? If not what are the open problems left to be answered? Is there any flaw in such proposal?

The more formal question would be if there is already a known physical candidate for such proposal even if such instance does not precisely resemble our universe literally, but only conceptually?

Comment: I don't think Susskind himself would claim that he has "solved" quantum gravity. Ideally, a full theory of quantum gravity would involve a system of non-perturbative equations that allow you to calculate to any desired precision any question involving strong-field gravity and quantum mechanics, and should reduce to GR and the Standard Model in appropriate limits. It should also make connection with experiment. Susskind's proposal is interesting but quite light on equations and does not provide a logical framework allowing you to calculate.

Comment: Besides the video, is there any paper by Susskind on the subject of the video???

Comment: You're asking if there's a candidate for a universe in which we might be able to solve quantum gravity? Yes. This usually involves adding SUSY as in Maldacena's 1997 breakthrough or going to lower dimensions as in JT gravity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, and this can be guessed from the modest number of citations his [GR = QM paper](https://inspirehep.net/literature/1615488) has received. [It](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.3716) [is](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.7856) [true](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.2933) that Einstein's equations have a connection to quantum information and this work form which Susskind extrapolates is certainly interesting. But it doesn't make any claim of being applicable to the most basic quantum gravity observables which have always been scattering amplitudes with internal or external gravitons. Standard QFT methods can only compute these if we introduce an unknown cut-off for the scale of new physics by hand. The most widely advocated proposal for improving this in real life goes something like the following.

1. Build very impressive experiments which establish the existence of small extra dimensions.
2. Perform even more impressive experiments to find constraints on their shapes.
3. Classify the string landscape to the point where these constraints are enough to point you to a unique vacuum.
4. Identify the QFT which is holographically dual to string theory around this background.
5. Solve or find a powerful approximation to this QFT.

These steps are very much still in their infancy.

Comment: If I'm not wrong you're pointing to observables in "our" universe. But what about observables in any conceivable hypothetical universe? Does his proposal give predictions for any observables in this very general sense?

Comment: I'm talking about most universes which are not dreamed up to be nice. If you pick the nicest one, which is $AdS_5 \times S^5$, you can skip steps 1-3. Then there are important papers finding evidence for the duality with $\mathcal{N} = 4$ Super Yang-Mills (step 4) and a growing body of work about how to analyze this theory with integrability (step 5). One case of quantum gravity is therefore under good control but this development is not related to the one in your link.

Comment: I'm gonna improve the question, I hope you can elaborate too. Thanks